# How to expand an OS X volume after removing a BootCamp partition manually?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have Macbook Pro 2015 with Yosemite installed.

I need help for my startup disk. I decided to delete my Windows to have more space on  Macintosh HD. I used BootCamp Assistant to delete the Windows partition but it said it can not be a single hard disk.

So I used Disk Utility to erase BootCamp and chose Mac OS Extended Journaled for it, but when I chose the **main disk** to partition it, it said that the disk needs to be repaired. In First Aid I chose Repair Disk, then when I went to the Partition tab I saw this and I cannot have a single disk and the BootCamp partition is free space now. How can I merge the two parts?

[image]

Comment: Please open Terminal.app and enter `sudo gpt -r show disk0` and `diskutil verifyDisk disk0`  and add both results to your answer by hitting the edit link beneath your question.

Comment: You don't so much merge partitions as you expand an existing partition into unpartitioned (empty) space. I believe you need to delete the other partition so there is nothing there to format and **then** you should be able to expand your macOS partition. But do post the results of klanomath's suggestion to be sure what exactly to do.

Comment: @klanomath
many thanks to you , i did what you said but nothing happend!

Comment: @A.Mir After typing a command you have to hit the Enter key to "execute" it. First enter the *sudo ...* command and hit enter, then the *diskutil ...* command and hit the enter key again.

Comment: @klanomath i did this,then what?

Comment: @A.Mir Then choose everything in the Terminal window with cmd-A, copy everything  with cmd-C and hit either the *edit* link just beneath your question or this link -> [edit](http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/262861/edit) and scroll to the end of your question. Then enter cmd-V to paste all and save the changes. I will repair the broken formatting.

Comment: @klanomath what about reinstalling macos and restore files from time machine??

Comment: You may reinstall OS X (or restore a Time machine backup), but reinstalling OS X usually doesn't change your partition map (or/and the size of *Macintosh HD*). You simply posted a screenshot which is almost useless, because it neither reveals the real partition map nor any sizes/partition types.

Comment: @klanomath even if i factory reset my macbook, it doesn't change the partition??

Comment: @klanomath because when i hold down Option key while booting there is still windows:((